# Multiple Declarations in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In [basic.scope.declarative]p4, one reads

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name, — (4.1) they shall all refer to the same entity …

A naïve reading might imply that the following code might be valid because "both declarations refer to the same entity":

```
int x;
int x;
```

One then might remember the one definition rule [basic.def.odr]p1. The above reasoning might apply only to declarations not to definitions. The distinction is spelled out in [basic.def]p2. For example, the following code is certainly valid:

```
extern int x;
extern int x;
```

The last example in [basic.def]p2 suggests then that the following code should be valid, but it does not compile (using MSVC2015).

```
struct B
{
    int y;
};

struct D : B
{
    using B::y;
    using B::y;
};
```

**Where is the problem?**

---

The error message is

> the using-declaration for 'B::y' cannot co-exist with the existing using-declaration for 'B::y'

Comment: You're overlooking the fact that your first quote doesn't imply that any such declarations are legal;  just that if they don't comply then they are illegal. They might be illegal for other reasons (and are, in this case).  In other words, "shall" means [necessary but not sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example from [namespace.udecl]p10 is exactly the same as yours:

```
struct B {
   int i;
};
struct X : B {
   using B::i;
   using B::i; // error: double member declaration
};
```

The error is backed up by [class.mem]p1:

> A member shall not be declared twice in the *member-specification*,
>   except that a nested class or member class template can be declared
>   and then later defined, and except that an enumeration can be
>   introduced with an *opaque-enum-declaration* and later redeclared with
>   an *enum-specifier*.

So you're on the right track. Multiple declarations are OK, as long as they don't break other rules (e.g. one definition, member specifications etc.)

The following, for example, is fine:

```
struct X;
struct X;
```

Or a more complex example:

```
struct X 
{
    struct A;
    struct A
    {
       int y;
    };
}; 

struct X;
struct X::A;
```

Comment: I just read [namespace.udecl]p10: *"A using-declaration is a declaration and can therefore be used repeatedly where (and only where) multiple
declarations are allowed."* I searched for the words "multiple declarations" and found 3 instances, none of which spells out where those places might be. I had no luck with "declared twice" either. So, I guess those places are within structures, classes, enumerations, and unions. Everywhere else seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered your own question by citing namespace.udecl/10. The example underneath (N3936) shows a location where multiple equivalent `using`-declarations are allowed:

```
namespace A {
    int i;
}
namespace A1 {
    using A::i;
    using A::i; // OK: double declaration
}
void f() {
    using A::i;
    using A::i; // error: double declaration
}
struct B {
    int i;
};
struct X : B {
    using B::i;
    using B::i; // error: double member declaration
};
```

Multiple `using`-declarations for a function are also allowed, at namespace *and* block scope. As to why they are not allowed for variables (objects) at block scope, I have no idea. Multiple equivalent member declarations are probably disallowed for two reasons:

- large potential for initialization order bugs
- it wasn't necessary historically, because the bodies of methods defined inline "see" members declared later in the same class (with the introduction of `decltype` in C++11, this reason is no longer as definitive)